# Css is not loaded on page using express / handlebars

Tags: css, node.js, express-handlebars

The first page loads the css correctly, however when clicking on the link that loads a handlebars with new url parameter, the css is not loaded.

Checking on the console, network tab, I could see that the application is trying to load the CSS file up one level as if there were another folder /styles.css.
I'm using node + express + handlebars.

Calling the css file in the index.html file:

The rest of the files are .handlebars loaded into the index.html file.

The problem occurs when executing the function:

```
app.get('/artistaslist/:letra', function(req, res){
```

In this image, note the url without the parameter the CSS is loaded correctly.

[image: image-1]

In this image, note the url with the parameter the CSS is NOT loaded. And the file path is added one more level, see the highlight in the image.

[image: image-2]

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Artista = require('./models/Artista')
// Para raw queries:
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');
const { Op } = require("sequelize"); // Para operações com like
//Configs
 // Template engine
 app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}))
 app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
 // Body parser - usado para pegar dados dos forms 
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
 app.use(bodyParser.json())
 
 //o recurso path no começo do código resolve todas as pastas abaixo da pasta view
 app.use("/views", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'views')));
 
// Rotas
 //Rota página iniciao
 app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/layouts/index.html');
 })
 // Rota lista de artistas cadastrados
 app.get('/artistaslist', function(req, res){
  Artista.findAll({order: [['nome_completo', 'ASC']]}).then(function(artistas){
  res.render(__dirname +'/views/layouts/artistaslist', {artistas: artistas}) 
  })  
 })
 //Rota para listar artistas iniciando por uma letra
 app.get('/artistaslist/:letra', function(req, res){
  Artista.findAll({
   where: {
    nome_completo: { 
     [Op.like]: req.params.letra + '%'
    }
   }
  }).then(function(artistas){
  res.render(__dirname +'/views/layouts/artistaslist', {artistas: artistas})
  console.log("Diretorio atual: "+ __dirname);
  })  
 })

 // Rota de cadastro de artistas
 app.get('/cadartista', function(req, res){
  res.render(__dirname +'/views/layouts/formulario')
 })
 
 //Rota para deletar um registro
 app.get('/deletar/:id', function(req, res){
  Artista.destroy({where: {'id': req.params.id}}).then(function(){
   res.send("Artista deletado com sucesso!")
  }).catch(function(erro){
   res.send("Ocorreu um erro: "+erro)
  })
 })
 
 app.post('/add', function(req, res){
  //Criando artista, acessando o Artistainsert
  Artista.create({
   nome_completo: req.body.nome,
   email: req.body.email,
   nacionalidade: req.body.selectNacionalidade,
   observ: req.body.obs
  }).then(function(){
   res.redirect('/artistaslist')
  }).catch(function(erro){
   res.send("Ocorreu um erro: "+ erro)
  })
 })

//Final
app.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log("Serv rodando na porta 3000");
});


//Parei na aula 20
```

I appreciate if someone can give me a help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing the page's "app.get" without pointing to the .handlebars file
From:

```html
app.get('artistaslist/:letra', function(req, res){
```

To:

```html
app.get('/:letra', function(req, res){
```